# Por que meu cancelAnimationFrame() não esta funcionado no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
class Objeto{
  constructor(){
    this.x = 10;
    this.y = 10;
    this.velY = 2;
  }
  dObjeto(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(10,this.y,100,100);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }

  stop(){
    cancelAnimationFrame(id);
  }
  anima(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    objeto.y += objeto.velY;
    objeto.dObjeto();
    //Eu queria que quando alcançasse o valor máximo ele parace com o método stop()
    if(objeto.y + objeto.velY > canvas.height || objeto.y + objeto.velY < 0){
      objeto.velY = -objeto.velY;
      objeto.stop();
    }
    id = requestAnimationFrame(objeto.anima);
  }
}

//Eventos
//Função para mecher na dimenssão da canvas
function canvasT(){
  canvas.width = 700;
  canvas.height = 450;
  canvas.style.border = 'solid';
}
canvasT();
var id;
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var objeto = new Objeto();
objeto.dObjeto();
objeto.anima();
window.addEventListener('keydown', objeto.pula, false);
//So funciona a cancelAnimationFrame() se eu apertar o click evento abaixo
window.addEventListener('click', objeto.stop, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque um `return;` após chamar `objeto.stop();` dentro do `anima()`, senão o código continuará na próxima linha `id = requestAnimationFrame(objeto.anima);` que continua a animação:

```js
window.onload = function(){
class Objeto{
  constructor(){
    this.x = 10;
    this.y = 10;
    this.velY = 2;
  }
  dObjeto(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(10,this.y,100,100);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }

  stop(){
    cancelAnimationFrame(id);
  }
  anima(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    objeto.y += objeto.velY;
    objeto.dObjeto();
    //Eu queria que quando alcançasse o valor máximo ele parace com o método stop()
    if(objeto.y + objeto.velY > canvas.height || objeto.y + objeto.velY < 0){
      objeto.velY = -objeto.velY;
      objeto.stop();
      console.log("PAROU!");
      return;
    }
    id = requestAnimationFrame(objeto.anima);
  }
}

//Eventos
//Função para mecher na dimenssão da canvas
function canvasT(){
  canvas.width = 700;
  canvas.height = 450;
  canvas.style.border = 'solid';
}
canvasT();
var id;
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var objeto = new Objeto();
objeto.dObjeto();
objeto.anima();
window.addEventListener('keydown', objeto.pula, false);
//So funciona a cancelAnimationFrame() se eu apertar o click evento abaixo
window.addEventListener('click', objeto.stop, false);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```